# ActiveAdmin rendering partial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, partials

I was following this [guide](http://www.patrickedelman.com/simple-charting-for-activeadmin/) to create a line graph in my Active Admin panel. But I am getting a missing template error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Admin::SellerGrowth#index

Showing /home/vedant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-fc1874f7d3b4/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

Missing partial metrics/_line_chart with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/vedant/rails/Instano-api/app/views"
  * "/home/vedant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-fc1874f7d3b4/app/views"
  * "/home/vedant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.1/app/views"
  * "/home/vedant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #2):
insert_tag active_admin_application.view_factory["page"]
```

my `admin/metrics/user.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Seller Growth"  do

  content do
    @metric = V1::Seller.group_by_day(:created_at).count
    render :partial => '/metrics/line_chart', :locals => {:metric => @metric}
  end

end
```

my `app/views/metrics/_line_chart.html.erb` :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
<%= line_chart metric %>
```

Just to make sure that I not miss-typed anything:
On running

```
find app/views/metrics/
```

I get

```
app/views/metrics/
app/views/metrics/_line_chart.html.erb
```

Comment: I have tried exactly the same tutorial and it worked for me, just need to take care at the files and partial naming.

Comment: I created the directories and file names as per the tutorial. But still I am getting this error. How did it work for you? could you share your code, make a gist or point out my naming mistake?

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67540/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-27618839-activeadmin-rendering-partial-error-2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

app/views/admin/seller_growth/metrics/_line_chart.html.erb

render :partial => 'line_chart', :locals => {:metric => @metric}

Comment: same error. as per the error page, rails is searching in `/app/views/`